# Which one is faster for socket programming in ubuntu? python, c++ , or pure c executable

Tags: performance, sockets, ubuntu

I'm programming a tcp/ip server for my game and i want to make it fastest code possible. the question is which one of the three executable files is faster to run in ubuntu?

- Python
- C++
- Pure C
- Other?

Comment: If you write the code correctly, every language would be equally (with negligible difference) fast.

Comment: As SOFe said, there are barely any differences between the languages, but i would recommend writing it in C/C++ merely because most of tutorials and examples out there are in these languages so it would help you write in a good and correct way